# Fullscreen Mode using ActionBarSherlock on Devices running API <11

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-manifest

Is there a way to go in fullscreen mode using ActionBarSherlock on Devices running API <11?

Further Information:

My app is using ActionBarSherlock and while testing on different devices i stumbled on a problem.

If i try tro launch an activity in fullscreen

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

on a Device running on a API lower than 11 the following error occured:

```
 05-29 10:12:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 05-29 10:12:54.436: E/AndroidRuntime(1034): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   start activity      ComponentInfo{de.osthessennews.osthessennewsapp/com.example.listview.PlayVideo}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock, Theme.Sherlock.Light,   Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a derivative.
```

The error occurs, cuz the Line in the Manifest isn't supported for Devices running on API's < 11.

So i know what is causing the problem, but i dont know how to resolve it. I hope one of you guys can help me.

Manifest Snipped:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"  
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"       
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
    >
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You Can do Programmatically :

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Use before `setContentView()`.

Comment: add getSupportActionBar().hide() to hide action bar also.

Answer (score 5):

The latest version of ABS (ActionBar Sherlock) still does not have a Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar or Theme.Sherlock.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen but you can always create a Fullscreen activity by hiding the ActionBar programmatically as explained on the previous answer.

But if you want to create a theme or style, include

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

on it, but that will only hide Android's status bar.

To hide the ActionBar in your activities (extending from SherlockActivity or SherlockFragmentActivity) code:

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

That will give you a NoActionBar.Fullscreen effect.