# Starting new activity from fullscreen activity causes status bar to cover action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, statusbar

I am using ActionBarSherlock lib. I have CameraActivity which has style set to fullscreen:

```
<activity
   android:name="pl.toptof.android.ui.activity.CameraActivity"
   android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled.NoActionBar.fullScreen"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

When I start new activity from this activity like that:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, PreviewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("PhotoURI",takenPhotoURL);
intent.putExtra("voteID",voteId);
CameraActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

Activity looks like it stayed in fullscreen mode and status bar is visible, and cover my actionbar. Theme of Preview activity is:

```
<application
        android:name="(...)"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled">

<activity
            android:name="pl.toptof.android.ui.activity.PreviewActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

The problem appears only on Sony Xperia Z device. On HTC Legend, HTC One, Nexus 4, Samsung Galaxy S3, Nexus 7, Samsung Galaxy Note it works fine. And screen of it: 
[image: status bar covers action bar]

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: how about adding the fullscreen property to the layout ??

Comment: Well yeah... that could fix the problem but I don't want fullscreen in PreviewAcivity. I would like to handle it proper way.

Comment: windowmanager does allow you to set it as fullscreen when the activity starts. And you could use it in the activity that you want as fullscreen other than previewsactivity

Comment: okay I've tried that but it will take time till I can give you response, I do not own Xperia Z so I can't test it - I have to wait for client response. But if someone has any other ideas I'd love to try them.

Comment: no issues, take ur time

Comment: okay it's not working, any other ideas how to fix it?

Comment: hey, add a theme to camera activity with an actionbar (i mean theme with an actionbar)

Comment: but if I do this then status bar in CameraActivity will be visible and my view will go crazy

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811951/fullscreen-mode-using-actionbarsherlock-on-devices-running-api-11, if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is fixed. What I have done is:

I have modified this way of starting new activity by

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this, PreviewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("PhotoURI",takenPhotoURL);
intent.putExtra("voteID",voteId);
CameraActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

adding

```
getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

before startActivity method. It's a bit tricky but status bar is sliding down before activity ends and everything works fine. When I return/start CameraActivity again it gets FLAG_FULLSCREEN onCreate again.